# How to call Customer custom attribute in front end?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]I created yes or no attribute. Attribute id ="authorised_dealer". I want to display in attribute value in front end.How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the custom attribute by:

```
$customerModel  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$attr = $customerModel->getData('authorised_dealer');
```

Comment: its not working....

Comment: Whats happening? Any errors?

Comment: No error Plz check above attachement

Comment: Are you correctly passing the customer id, in your case for the attached screen shot, it would be '$customerId = 138'. Also if you replace 'authorised_dealer' (from getData function) with 'email', does that then work?

Comment: Can you please send that how load customer id.

Comment: Where do you want to load a customer from?

Comment: I have market place on seller page i need to display authorized dealer or not

Comment: Ok, this is a separate question so please accept my answer if it is correct. Open another question and i will help you with that.